# JQuery load() inside for loop

Tags: jquery, loops, for-loop, load, wait

I'm trying to write a Greasemonkey script where different pages are loaded with `.load()` using a for loop and store some of their informations in `localStorage`.
My Problem: because `.load()` is asynchronous it doesn't work well. My script just stores the Last value I am trying to store. I think that is because i use the `var i` inside the callback function, and when the callback function is fired `i` has already another value.

```
for (var i = 0; i < plantsDiv.length; i++)
{
   objectid = plantsDiv[i].getAttribute('objectid');    
   $("#wrap").load("index.php?objectid="+ objectid,function(){
      //[...] what is happening
      window.localStorage.setItem(objectid,value);
   });
}
```

When i insert `alert("foo")` between the callback function and the end of the for loop everything works, because the `.load` function is loaded, while i am clicking "ok" in the alert window.
Is there any way to let the for loop wait until the whole `.load` is executed?

Thanks for your help, and sorry for my Bad english :)

Comment: Put a `var` before `objectid = plantsDiv[i].getAttribute('objectid');`

Comment: thanks for your help, but thats not solving my problem, i already initialized this variable before.

Comment: That *is* the problem - it's not `i` that's the issue.  Don't declare it outside the loop - declare it inside ;)

Comment: Tried declaring inside. And sadly it's not working anyway :(

Comment: Where does `value` come from?

Comment: I take two integers out of the loaded document after inserting it into the page and sum them up.

Comment: $("#wrap") your problem is here, make the id dynamic too, thus: $("#wrap<?=$id?>")

Answer (score 1):

The `load()` function is [pretty much the same](http://api.jquery.com/load/) as a `get()` function -

> This method is the simplest way to fetch data from the server. It is
>   roughly equivalent to $.get(url, data, success) except that it is a
>   method rather than global function and it has an implicit callback
>   function.

By using the slightly more verbose `ajax()` function, you'll be able to specify the request to be *synchronous* with `async` set to false. Perhaps this will solve your issue.

A simple, synchronous ajax call :

```
$.ajax({
  url: "example.php",
  data : yourData,
  async : false
},function(response){
  // this is the callback
});
```

References -

- [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
- [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)
- [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 0):

If the objective is not loading the content into an element and instead is to get the content and save it into localStorage you should user $.get (or $.post if you want to post data).

jQuery ajax functions return a jqXHR object, which is derived from a Deferred object, so you can use .done() for success and .fail() for failure:

```
$.get("index.php?objectid="+ objectid)
.done(function(data) {
    window.localStorage.setItem(objectid,data);
})
.fail(function() {
    // try again later?
});
```

Edit: Note that the requests will still be launched asynchronously and in this case you may have a lot of parallel requests, the code in the done (or fail) blocks will be run when the response of each request is received.

Comment: I'm inserting it into the Page and then store parts of it :/

Comment: but you are inserting the contents of multiple requests into the same element (id #wrap), you have no guarantee on what response is received first, and load overwrites existing content.

Comment: I know, that I'm inserting them into the same element. I insert the content using `load`, then store the content I need into localStorage. After that the next .load should be executed...

Comment: The way you are describing the behavior makes me think you believe .load is synchronous. There is no defined order in which the content is loaded and some of the content wont ever be visible. But i guess if it works for you its ok.

Comment: I know, that it isn't synchronous. And i don't need any specific order. I don't even need them to be seen by the User, but i have to include them into the page for some ms because I can't access them (e.g. with `document.getElementById("")`) without including  it 'cause the files I'm trying to load are not valid xml files...